# map file contents to file type

Tags: python, file

Whole idea is to read variables from file, that also has imports in it:
**RULES**:
1) file is untouchable (we can read it, but no modifications)
2) we don't want to import variables from files imports (only variables from the file)
3) we do not crate temp files (assume no write access)

My idea has two steps:
1) (done), read file to memory and comment all import lines
2) use imp to import values
    2a) map file contents back to file type
    2b) `use imp.load_source()`
    2c)  `{key: value for key, value in foo.__dict__.iteritems() if not key.startswith('_')}`

Stuck on `2a`, can anyone help/support me, pls?

**EXAMPLE FILE**:

```
# from os import *
myvar = 'aaa'
```

Comment: We need a [mcve] to answer your question - namely, we need to see what your input file looks like and what the expected result is.

Comment: I've added example file. You can have it as stringIO object, however imp.load_source requires path. I am looking for solution to that

Comment: More importantly, you should be clearer about what output you want to get. Is it `['myvar']`? Or is it `{'myvar': 'aaa'}`? Or is it something else entirely?

Comment: How about `exec` on the string containing the uncommented file? `exec` is unsafe and should only be used on trusted input though (but the same is probably true for importing as well)

Comment: Aran-Fey it's {'myvar': 'aaa'}

Comment: MFreidank, can you give me please an example?

Comment: check the solution of @Serge Ballesta - it has what I was referring to.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I have correctly understood your requirements, the usually *evil* `eval` could help here. It is generally frowned upon because executing arbitrary code is unsafe, but not more unsafe than loading an arbitrary script.

So assuming that you were able to read a file and comment and comment all import statements and that you have the resulting script in a string `script_str`, you could simply do:

```
glob = {}  # or glob = globals() if you want current globals to be accessible
loc = {}
exec(script_str, glob, loc)
vars = { key:loc[key] for key in loc if not key.startswith('_') }
```

The problem is that commenting some lines from a script may result in an incorrect script or could give wrong results. Example:

```
from os import SEEK_END

how = SEEK_END
```

It should result in `{ "how": 2 }`. Unfortunately without commenting the import, you will get `{'SEEK_END': 2, 'how': 2}`, but after commenting, the `exec` call will raise an exception `NameError: name 'SEEK_END' is not defined`.

My opinion is that fixing it for the most general case will be hard...

Comment: That is EXACTLY what I was looking for! You've also added easy to understand description with potential issues, I thank you very much for that and I'd put more up if I could!